# Why my UWP package is being rejected?

Tags: c#, uwp, ads

I've created a pretty simple app that uses banner ads.

App works great with debuging mode with ads test ads showing up. But when I'm creating a appxupload and uploading it to store I'm getting error.

> Your package Microsoft.Advertising.Xaml specifies version 10.1707.2.0, but 10.0.0.0 is the minimum available version.

What exactly is the problem, why package is getting rejected and how can it be resolved?

Answer (score 1):

According to the description of the error, you have installed Microsoft.Advertising.Xaml package which can't work on the Windows version below 10.1707.2.0 (which hasn't even been released to the general public). Your app declares that it can work on every version of Windows 10. This is in a collision.

Comment: Yes. According to [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/4ee89c14-c13c-4d4a-b646-25d874c1624f/uwp-javascript-latest-advertising-libraries?forum=aiasdk), the package of that version has not been uploaded to the Store by related team. I will report this problem. Currently, you can try uninstalling the 10.0.2 `MicrosoftStoreServicesSDK.msi` and install the previous version from NuGet package so that you can upload your submission firstly.

Answer (score 1):

Had the EXACT same problem. Finally got mine to work by uninstalling the MSI from https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AdMediator.MicrosoftAdvertisingSDK and installing the `Microsoft.Advertising.XAML` from NUGET package manager. It was only 1 version earlier, but let me publish my app to the store.

Comment: Are you seeing ads in your app? Because I'm not.

Comment: Yes. I see advertising, and the advertising results on the console.

Comment: So do I now, but eCPM is too low and what do you mean results on console.